# Restrict page access for normal users and admin

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

I'm currently developing an application that manages the students, courses, professors ... of a university. I already implemented the authentication with Spring Security using Jpa. There are 2 type of users : Administrator and Professor. The Administrator should have access to all pages that have the pattern : `"/management/student*" , "/management/professor/*" , "/management/course*"` and the professor can only have access to the url `"/management/rooms"` ( Because he should be able to book a room to do his lecture). 
I have tried to use `hasRole("ADMIN")`method but I don't know how can I add the Authority to a particular entity.
The Professor Class extends the following User Class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Data
public class User implements Serializable, UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String username;

    private String password;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Role> roles;

    @Override
    public List<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        roles.forEach(role -> authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.toString())));

        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {

        return false;
    }

    public void grantAuthority(Role authority) {
        if (roles == null) {
            roles = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        roles.add(authority);
    }
}
```

The Professor Class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Professor")
@Data
public class Professor extends User implements Serializable{

//fields like name email etc ...

}
```

The UserRepository Interface :

```
public interface UserRepository {
        @Query(" select u from User u " +
                " where u.username = ?1")
        Optional<User> findUserWithName(String username);

}
```

This is my SecurityConfig class where I want to define the page restrictions :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf()
            .disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint() {
            })
        .and()
            .authenticationProvider(getProvider())
            .formLogin()
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .successHandler(new AuthentificationLoginSuccessHandler())
            .failureHandler(new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler())
        .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutSuccessHandler(new AuthentificationLogoutSuccessHandler())
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/logout").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/management/student*","/management/professor*").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/management/rooms*").hasRole("PROFESSOR");
    }

    private class AuthentificationLoginSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        }
    }

    private class AuthentificationLogoutSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler {
        @Override
        public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider getProvider() {
        AuthProvider provider = new AuthProvider();
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        return provider;
    }
```

Any Recommendations please ?

Comment: Any help here please ?

Comment: Roles need a "ROLE_" prefix. Depending on your "Role" class, you might need to do "new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role))"

Comment: Thank you so much for answering , so each time I'm inserting a newly created user in my database I should assign to it the required role?

Comment: So I should not be using Role enumeration ?

Comment: Your users do need a role, so yes, make sure each user has an entry for ElementCollection "roles". The second thing to make sure is that the SimpleGrantedAuthority is created with "ROLE_ADMIN" and not just "ADMIN"

Comment: Ok Thank you so much that Helped me a lot. I Have changed the architecture a little bit, I think I managed to set up the roles. I also set up the loginProcessingUrl with ``` .loginProcessingUrl("/signin") ``` and in the form i wrote method="/signin" , But it seems like the url is not recognized . Do you have any recommendation ?

Comment: I am getting the whitelabel error page after submitting

Comment: The error is : There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).